# Can a C++ allocator be final?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, final, allocator

The [cppreference page for the *Allocator* requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) does not say that an *Allocator* must be inheritable, i.e. it does not say that an *Allocator* must not be final.

However, in many libraries, an allocator is privately inherited to take advantage of the empty base class optimization for stateless allocators. For example:

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class Dummy_vector :private A {
    // ...
    A get_alloc() const
    {
        return static_cast<A>(*this);
    }
    // ...
};
```

If `A` is final, this implementation breaks.

**Can an *Allocator* be final? Did I miss something? Or should such implementation include special code for final *Allocator*s?**

(Note: by "special code for final *Allocator*s," I mean something like this:

```
template <
    typename T,
    typename A = std::allocator<T>,
    bool = std::is_final<A>
>
class Dummy_vector :private A {
    // version for nonfinal allocators
    // ...
    A get_alloc() const
    {
        return static_cast<A>(*this);
    }
    // ...
};

template <typename T, typename A>
class Dummy_vector<T, A, true> {
    // special version for final allocators
};
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a problem. See also [C++ Standard Library Defect Report 2112](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2112). The standard does not require that an allocator type can be derived from. However, the standard also doesn't specify that an implementation derive from the allocator type. Thus, the consensus seems to be that this is to be considered the implementation's fault for not checking whether the allocator type can be derived from…

Comment: Actually, I guess it should better be considered a bug in the standard library implementation…

Comment: Thank you! I agree that the standard contains a logic fault regarding "An allocator cannot be a non-class type [...] Thus, it is always possible to create a derived class from an allocator." in that it fails to consider final. The standard library implementation is then innocent ;-)

Comment: OK. I will check for `final` when I write my containers anyway.

Comment: @L.F. I edited my answer; I removed the part where I called this a bug in the standard. I overlooked that the defect report has been marked as resolved with C++14. The discussion there would lead me to the conclusion that the problem is, at least since C++14, to be considered a problem with the implementation rather than the specification…

Comment: @L.F. starting with C++ 20, the [\[\[no_unique_address\]\]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) attribute should do away with the reasons to derive from user-provided types in cases such as this, and all the problems that doing so entails…

Comment: Oh yeah! Now `final` won't matter.